# How to query in sqlite fts3 table using "-*"?

Tags: android, sqlite, full-text-search, fts3

I have a fts3 table named tab and a lot of entries in it. When I run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE key MATCH 'an*';
```

I get the results like this:

```
an
anul
an-
```

But when I run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE key MATCH 'an-*';
```

it still results the "an" entry. The result would be like:

```
an
an-
```

How can I write my query so the result woudn't be "an", but only those entries that actually contains the character "-"?

Comment: `-` is a reserved character, used for set operations, if I am reading the documentation correctly. Unfortunately, I do not see what the syntax is to escape characters here. You could try `an\-*`.

Comment: You could use double quotes inside single quotes to make it to work. eg:  ' "sub-folder" '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the default [tokenizer](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#tokenizer) rules, `-` separates words, and is otherwise ignored.

You have to search for the word `an` first, and check for the hyphen afterwards:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
WHERE key MATCH 'an'
  AND key LIKE 'an-%';
```